# Можно ли частично публиковать файлы классов/контроллеров в проекте MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Знаю что можно публиковать cshtml страницы и файлы ресурсов/картинок и тд. Они спокойно публикуются. А можно ли опубликовать файлы классов/контроллеров? Когда я попробовал изменения не применялись.

Comment: Для каких целей это нужно?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko чтобы не публиковать весь проект целиком каждый раз когда меняешь модели и контроллеры

Comment: что тут под публикацией имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy имеется ввиду когда проект заливается на боевой веб сервер